# Interactive plotting of 3D data in a web app

Tags: web-applications, 3d, drawing, interactive

I need to create a web app that allows the user to graphically analyze multivariate data. In my vision, the users will select three (out of the many available) variables that they want to see, and the app will plot them. After that the users will get the opportunity to interactively explore the graphs.

There is a [site](http://biomodel.uah.es/Jmol/plots/phase-diagrams/inicio.htm) that demonstrates using [JMol](http://jmol.sourceforge.net/) - an open-source Java viewer for chemical structures in 3D to plot data in 3d. The [result](http://biomodel.uah.es/Jmol/plots/phase-diagrams/inicio.htm) is pretty neat, but I would feel more comfortable to use a tool that is dedicated to plotting data, as I suspect such a tool would be more easy to operate and would provide more options. Unfortunately, I  cannot find any alternative that will both work in 3D and will provide interactive access to the plot. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Migrated this question from webapps.stackexchange.com http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/10276/interactive-plotting-of-3d-data-in-a-web-app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JMathPlot is [what I need](http://jmathtools.berlios.de/doku.php?id=cases:3dplots)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

JQuery Flot is a great graphing library for JavaScript. I believe it can do 3D graphs. Take a look http://code.google.com/p/flot/

Comment: Nope, according to the examples, Flot can't produce 3D graphs.